# Autocovariance of an AR(3) process

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I am given a general equation of an AR(3) process :

$Y_t\:=\:e_t\:+\:\Phi _1\:Y_{t-1}+\:\Phi _2Y_{t-2}\:\:+\:\Phi _3Y_{t-3}$

I want to find the $\gamma _0$ of the AR(3) process but I am not too sure how should i go about doing it.

Do I take the variance of both sides of the AR(3) process? Or should I use Yule-Walker equations and derive the $\gamma _0$ from there?

Comment: OH yes sorry, edited!

Comment: Is this a homework related question? If so, please add the tag `self-study` to your question and read this [information](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: what is $\gamma_0$?

Comment: That is common notation for the variance of the process in this context